# Calculate/infer percentile of a number not in the original data set

Tags: statistics, percentile

Let's say I have a set of any 10 numbers and I've calculated some percentiles for them, e.g. 40th, 45th, 50th. Then I have an 11th number that falls within the minimum and maximum values of the original 10.

Example

x=(90,100,108,110,111,115,116,118,120,134)

the 40th, 45th, and 50th percentiles are 110.6, 111.2, and 113 respectively.

The 11th number is 112. Can we assume that all numbers are present between 111 and 115 such that 112 has a percentile that can be calculated/estimated without adding 112 to the set. Adding 112 to the set changes N and then also changes the 40th, 45th, and 50th percentiles.

In the 11 number set, x=(90,100,108,110,111, 112, 115,116,118,120,134)
The 40th, 45th, and 50th percentiles, calculated in the same manner as above, are now 111, 111.5, 112.

Asked another way, can we determine what percentile 112 is where all other percentiles from the original set of 10 do not change? Or is this fundamentally not what percentiles are?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking: Suppose my 10 numbers are $x = (90, 100, 108, 110, 111, 115, 116, 118, 120, 134).$ Different texts and software programs have slightly different methods of finding percentiles. According to R the 40th, 45th, 50th percentiles are 110.6, 111.2, 113, respectively. Note that percentiles need not be among the original **10** numbers. (Which of the ten would be _exactly_ the 45th percentile?) Now say my 11th number is 112. You might say it would be btw the 45th and 50th percentile?. But if I include 112 in the dataset then 47th and 48th pctles are 111.7 and 111.8, resp.

Comment: ... Another approach: The sample mean and SD of my 10 numbers are 112.2 and 11.82, resp. I assume the dist'n is normal. I could look at the _estimated_ dist'n NORM($\mu$=112.2, $\sigma$=11.82) and find that about 0.4933 of the probability in that dist'n falls below 112, making 112 quantile .4933 of that dist'n--roughly the 49th percentile. // I hope one of these approaches helps you understand your question. Please edit your Question above if you can make it less ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks BruceET. I edited the original question to try and clarify. I understand your points, and it almost seems like i can just solve for every percentiles until i come up with a percentile that matches the outside number without incorporating the extra number into the original data set.

Comment: I don't fully understand what purpose or application you have in mind. Roughly speaking, your idea seems OK.

Comment: A general use would be, I have 1000 height measurements representing a population. I wasn't sampled in that population, and my specific height isn't in the data set. But my height is within the range of values. If percentiles quantify what values are at or below that percentile, it seems like I could estimate and say for this population, I'm at the X percentile in height, but I'm not a part of that population, so I would not want to include my data in that sample. I just want to know where I would be.

Comment: Clearer now:  I'd use my 2nd method above. Use sample mean $\bar X$ and SD $S$ of the 1000 measurements to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for the population. Then find the probability in that population of being less than your height. One approach is to use $P(Z \le \frac{y-\bar X}{S})$ and normal CDF tables, where $y$ is your height. // Suppose $\bar X = 59, S =3.5, y =61.$ Then $P(Z \le 0.57) = 0.7157$ and you're at about the 72nd percentile.

Comment: Thanks so much! This makes pretty good sense. I'm going to assume this method is not as useful for skewed data. Much of what I'm looking at will not be normal.

Comment: If the data are obviously skewed, it might be better just to take the fraction of the 1000 observations below your height. Most samples of heights are close to normal, but this may not be the case if the population from which the 1000 are drawn is highly diverse (e.g. including many ages, some children). Percentiles are often rounded to the nearest integer. With 1000 heights rounded to nearest inch, you may find your own height on the list.